# International driver's licence (IDD): is this site reliable?

Tags: driving-licenses

I'm stuck in a foreign destination without an IDD, and apparently the official way of doing it for me is to do it before the trip.

However, I found that page: http://www.international-license.com/
They do it and delivery it for you whereever you are or almost.

Have you guys had a past experience with this enterprise? Are they reliable? They clearly mention that

> Our translation has no official status and does not confer any legal
>   privileges or rights on consumers.

but what does it mean? Does it mean it is totally useless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not "useless", it just has a different goal.

Their website clearly states the difference between their products and a government issued International license:

> These unofficial documents will help you overcome language differences when traveling.

So the goal of their products is only to help you with the language difference, that's all. Plus they offer to save some document on your smartphone in case you lose the translating document.

Moreover, as they state,

> International driving permits, which are booklets issued by governmental agencies or private organizations designated by a country's government, are the only official translation of a person's driver's license.

In other words, you should ask the government which issued your driving license for a valid International license. Their product will not be considered as valid, anywhere you go.

Deciding if it is worth it is up to you.

Comment: that's what I thought too... But then, to me this page sounds like a ripoff

Comment: @Sebas It all depends on where your original DL is from and where you're going...

Comment: I agree with @Karlson, if you go to a country where they use a different alphabet, a different color for DL, when you show yours they might say well, prove it's not a fake one!

Comment: Yeah well that's the point of the IDD. But this website apparently does not prove it's not a fake one, actually.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is useless.

The reason is that there are two cases. The first case is that you are allowed to use your foreign driving license. For example, a tourist from the USA may drive with his own license six months in Germany. But that is only allowed because Germany and the USA have a reciprocity convention, in this case you do not need this IDD. Simply ask your embassy if your driving license is accepted.

The second case is that you need an IDP which is for example the case for an Indian citizen driving in Germany. Then it is not only useless, but outright dangerous because it could be interpreted as forgery (§276). Germany e.g. is very strict in this case, the maximum penalty are fines up to thousands of € or two years in prison.

Answer (score 6):

Be very careful

The site you refer to http://www.international-license.com/ issues an "International Drivers **License**". This is a supposed license card with your details on. It is not legally recognized anywhere in the world.

An International Driving **Permit** is a different document and is legally recognized under convention. It is a paper booklet which is basically just a language translation of your proper license and normally issued by your home Automobile Association as authorized by your government. This document is recognized in any country which is signatory to the convention.

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit

EDIT: Most countries require you to apply for your International Driving Permit in person with original documents, which effectively means that you cannot get one once you have left home. But if your license was issued in the USA then you can get one from the AAA by mail: http://www.aaa.com/vacation/idpf.html

Comment: Can get a New Zealand one online from anywhere in the world - no "in person" requirement there either

Answer (score 2):

If you go where it says [HOW it works](http://www.international-license.com/en/the-idd/requirements-how-it-works.html) you will see that

> The International Driver's Document will help break the language
>   barrier when traveling. Our high quality translation booklet
>   translates your valid driver's license in 9 languages

and in the first page it also says

> You only need your driver's license to apply

So In my opinion makes it clear that doesn't have the same value with the real one, it is just a copy translated in other languages and you need your official one in order to get the copy, but that's only my assumptions.

I can only advice you to go to a police station or an embassy in order to tell you what to do.